# for Which values $w$ the SOR method is convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, relaxations

hope you can help me, I've got stuck on this.

Consider the following matrix.
$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & p\\
-p & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

for which $w$ values the SOR method is convergent?

thanks!, Cheers.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the values of p in the matrix A?

Answer (score 0):

Express $A$ as $A = D - L - U$, where $D$ is diagonal, $L$ is strictly lower triangular, and $U$ is strictly upper triangular. Then the SOR iteration matrix is

$$
H_\omega = (D-\omega L)^{-1}((1-\omega)D + \omega U)
$$

The SOR method converges if the spectral radius $\rho(H_\omega) < 1$. Thus, you need to find all $\omega$ such that $\rho(H_\omega) < 1$.